# Реализация поддержки мультиязычности на asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Добрый день!

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте хороший обучающий ресурс по реализации поддержки мультиязычности на asp.net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее надежный источник:
[Официальная документация Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)

Самый распространенный и простой способ - файл ресурсов, в котором необходимо вести все локализируемые строки приложения.

В остальном, советую читать блоги разных разработчиков, которые работают с данной задачей. Ибо проблем там хватает.